# Can not resolve import LocalBroadcastManager on statement android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, localbroadcastmanager

I got this error while importing an eclipse project to Android studio. It shows a suggestion Add library `Gradle: com.android.support:support-core-utils-27.1.1` to classpath. I have added the library in my `build.gradle` file.

Here is my gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.tracking"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 27
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()

}
}

dependencies {


implementation project(':asciiProtocol')
implementation project(':deviceList')
implementation project(':captureActivity')
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1"
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation files('libs/opencsv-2.3.jar')
implementation files('libs/rfid.reader.api.jar')
implementation files('libs/scannercontrol.jar')
implementation files('libs/Zebra.jar')

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '27.1.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I googled it but I could not find a proper solution for this. However, I tried the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082990/cant-add-localbroadcastmanager-to-project-in-android-studio?answertab=active#tab-top) that isn't the right solution. Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Did you try to `Clean Project` and then `Make Project` in android studio's Build tab?

Answer (score 43):

I faced the same problem, then I noticed Google divided the v4 support library to multiple packages.

> Note: Prior to Support Library revision 24.2.0, there was a single v4 support library. That library was divided into multiple modules to improve efficiency. For backwards compatibility, if you list support-v4 in your Gradle script, your APK will include all of the v4 modules. However, to reduce APK size, we recommend that you just list the specific modules your app needs.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#v4

Then I checked LocalBroadcast page. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager

At the page top, there is description

> belongs to Maven artifact com.android.support:localbroadcastmanager:28.0.0-alpha1

When I faced this problem, the v28.0.0 (not alpha) has been available.

In the end, I changed settings in my `build.gradle`.

**before**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

**after**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:localbroadcastmanager:28.0.0'
```

**AndroidX**

```
implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
```

Comment: For androidx you can use: `implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'`

Comment: you can now replace `implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'` with the new: `implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'` & `'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'`

Answer (score 29):

This happened to me while migrating for AndroidX and the solution was to replace "`import androidx.core.content.LocalBroadcastManager;`" with `import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;`

Edited, as required to include the implementation, please don't forget dependency:

```
implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
```

Noting that Target & Build version are:

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
```

Comment: As called out by Dennis in another answer, make sure you include the dependency too:
  implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'

Comment: This solution worked great at SDK version 28 but in SDK version 29  this doesn't solve problem.

Comment: the solution is working for : '    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
'

Answer (score 4):

Use this

import **androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;**

instead of

import androidx.core.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

Answer (score 3):

For newer Android version, you should try to add this to gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

and then add this dependency to build.gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

Comment: the dependency is correct but no need for `android.enableJetifier=true`

Answer (score 1):

After lot of searching and R&D i found some solution. This is working for me i hope this is helping you.

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
```